Road cloud points estimation from static monocular camera
I'm currently working on a project involving cloud point estimation using a static monocular camera. In this project, I capture videos of cars on a road, which can have various shapes. My objective is to extract the contact points between the wheels and the road from these videos.
To achieve this, I've fine-tuned an object detection network to detect the wheels. Then, I've fitted ellipses to obtain the proper shape of the wheels, from which I've extracted the contact points.
My question pertains to converting the sequence of points from pixel coordinates (u, v) to 3D world coordinates. Currently, I'm utilizing a depth estimation model, which is effective, but I aim to transition to classical computer vision methods.
My proposed procedure involves calibrating the camera using a classic chessboard pattern with cv2.calibrateCamera(). This provides me with the intrinsic parameters, including the camera matrix (K). From my understanding, to estimate the translation vector (tvec) and rotation vector (rvec) (i.e., the extrinsic parameters), I need to employ the PnP algorithm.
However, I'm uncertain how to apply PnP in my specific setting. Can I use a chessboard for PnP calibration and then use the same tvec and rvec for each video, even if the scenes are completely different? If so, how should I proceed with the chessboard calibration, i.e. how can I choose the known 2D and 3D points? If not, what alternative approach should I consider?
I appreciate any assistance or insights.
